# Передать helper в шаблон

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

Подключил к CodeIgniter'у Twig шаблонизатор. Кто подскажет, как в шаблон передать хелперы, чтобы их там можно было использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Загрузи его в контроллере (`$this->load->helper('нужный');`) и используй в отображении.